# magento2 observer event

Tags: magento2

what is the equivalent event name in magento 2 for the below: **controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index">
    <!--<observer name="controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\createSearchResultPage"/> -->
    <observer name="controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Observer"/> 
                                                                            <!-- method="createSearchResultPage" attribute removed-->
</event>
```

Comment: controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index this event is also work in magento2 @Sachin

Comment: controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index this is correct event in magento 2, controller_action_predispatch event is load in all pages, whereas controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index event is load only catalogsearch result page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index` this event execute in `M2`.

As @Rakesh said `controller_action_predispatch` event is called before any other event is called and `controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index` event is execute only for catalog search result.

Comment: Why downvote ? Can anyone tell me ?